# KeyError - comparing set with excel cell in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Hello in the below code I'm trying to compare a set with an excel cell

```
s = [a]
d=b
loc_file=r"C:\\Users\\Public\Downloads\\media_bias.xlsx"
data=p.read_excel(loc_file, index_col=0)

print("\n ")
print(data)
print("\n")

for i in range(0,43):
    for j in range (0,43):
        if data[i][j]==s:
            print("found")
```

the error I'm encountering are: -

```
  File "d:\python script & program\Media Bais Detector.py", line 31, in detec
    if data[i][j]==s:
  File "C:\Users\SAYYED VIQUAR AHED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\SAYYED VIQUAR AHED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0
```

Thanks for reading the code

Answer (score 0):

> KeyError: 0

Your `data` frame is indexed by the Excel column A. In order to use integer indexes, use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing):

```
        if data.iloc[i][j]==s:
```

Note that it's at least unlikely that an Excel cell contains a list `[a]`; perhaps you meant

```
        if data.iloc[i][j] in s:
```

To be sure, you'd have to post the file content.